# Do Pull Requests Automatically Get Updated?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a github repo on my personal github account called docs.  I've forked that from another github repo that is the primary of these docs.

Last week, I made a bunch of changes to a branch on my personal github and made a pull request to the primary. (the server I originally forked).

They have not merged that pull request yet.

I've made some more changes to the same branch.

My question is do I need to do anything to get my latest changes in or are they pulling from my personal repo?

When I went to the github UI, it was not obvious how to create another pull request and then invalidate the first one.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, if you have an outstanding pull request in GitHub, and you want to update the source (feature) branch, all you need to do is push again and the pull request will update automatically.

This is the default behavior at least, unless your admin has done something to change this.  Other Git repositories, such as Bitbucket, also behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it helps in your case but if you're working on the same repo. GitHub provides action which automatically updates your open PR without any manual process or checking to keep your PR updated.

For more details please check [GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/auto-update)